# SQLight 3: append table

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I have a `table1` with column attributes `col1 col2 col3` which is filled with some data, say matrix `A`. I get new data with attributes `col2 col3 col4` - they come in a form of a list with attribute names and a matrix `B` of data themselves.

I want to add the new data to the existing `table1` to get the structure like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a11  a12  a13  -
     ...
aN1  aN2  aN3  -
-    b11  b12  b13
-         ...
-    bM1  bM2  bM3
```

Is there any easy way to do it? Maybe create a new temporary table first, append it somehow to the existing one and delete it?

Additionally, I want to be able to check for the new data if they have intersection by `col2` with some existing data, e.g. if `b11` is equal to any of `ai2`.

p.s. I use sqlite3 package from Python3 - don't know if it brings any limitation to SQLite functionality...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ALTER method?

```
example=sqlite3.connect('your_database_name.db')
cursor=example.cursor()
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN your_data TEXT')
```

or where it says "TEXT", you put whatever your data type is "REAL", "INT"
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for hint. But how about intersection of the column names? Is there a way to specify column attributes (col1, col2, col4, col4 names)?

Comment: let me experiment this and i will get back to you